# Convert 2D Object from the scene in 3D Arcore

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I want to convert a 2D object from the scene in 3D .Any suggestion about How can I do it using Arcore and Unity?

Comment: I am down voting this because your question is not clear at all. What do you mean converting 2D object to 3D?

Comment: I have an Object that is in 2d(like an image or a panel)and I want to transform the content of that panel in 3D .

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/)

Comment: Yes,but I don't want to have a database with that image and it corresponding 3D object .I want a method that automatically convert an input image 2d in 3D.Is any possibility?

Comment: I do not see how that would be possible sorry